# Visual Studio MVC debug launch route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When I hit debug (shift+F5) I want the launch route to be

`localhost:XXXX/Controller/Action`

Instead of

`localhost:XXXX/Views/Controller/Action.cshtml`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Visual Studio will often automatically attempt to go to the current page that is selected when debugging your application (thus attempting to access your current `.cshtml` page).

**Setting a Default Start Action**

[image]

If you want to set a particular Action or URL to be launched when running your application, you can do so through the following steps :

1. **Right-click your Project** within the Solution Explorer.
2. Choose **Properties**.
3. Select the **Web** tab on the left-hand side.
4. Under the Start Page section, define the **Specific Page** you would like to default to when the application is launched.
5. **Save your changes**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your using Visual Studio 2015 or 2013: Project Properties -> Web (tab) -> check `Start Url` and enter in the desired URL.